# Rails nested form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I don't understand why my file_field disappears when I set nested_attributes

MY MODELS:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :asset_attributes

     has_one :asset
     accepts_nested_attributes_for :asset
end


class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base

   attr_accessible :item_id, :photo
   belongs_to :item


end
```

MY HTML:

```
<%= form_for @item do |f| %>

    <%= f.fields_for :asset do |asset| %>
        <%= asset.file_field :photo %>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Why, when I set `accept_nested_attributes_for :asset`, file_fields disappears?

This form_for is for existing @item. I first create @item because I need item_id - so form_for is for update action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to build a relational object of `asset`. In the controller action try :

```
def new
  @item = Item.new
  @item.build_asset
end
```

And for the edit action, if there is a association for item and asset...then only the nested attributes will appear